# Find entities from a table based on multiple property lookups in another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I have 2 tables as defined below:

1. Table 1  - Persons
2. Table 2  - Lookups

Persons

```
-----------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Age | Gender | Address | Nationality
------------------------------------------------
1  | Ram  | 30  | Male   | Hyderabad| Indian <br/>
2  | Raj  | 30  | Male   | Delhi    | Indian <br/>
```

Lookups

```
------------------------------------------
 LookupId  |  Key        |  Value
------------------------------------------
     1     | Age         |  30
     2     | Gender      |  Male
     3     | Address     |  Chennai
     4     | Nationality |  Indian
     5     | Age         |  24
     6     | Gender      |  Male
     7     | Address     |  Hyderabad
     8     | Nationality |  Indian
     9     | Age         |  30
    10     | Gender      |  Male
    11     | Address     |  Delhi
    12     | Nationality |  Indian
    13     | Age         |  34
    14     | Gender      |  Female
    15     | Address     |  Mumbai
    16     | Nationality |  Indian
```

Based on above data, what is the recommended or best way to fetch the Person information from Persons tables while there can be multiple lookups selected by the user.

For example: 
    For lookupIds 1, 2, 8 both person Ids 1 and 2 should be returned.
    For lookupIds 1, 2, 7, 8 person Id 1 would be returned.
    For lookupIds 5, 6, 7, 8 no record would be returned and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to build your dynamic sql statement based on the values selected. This query will provide you the actual query that you will have to run against the persons table

```
WITH STMT
AS
(
select id,
REPLACE(stuff((
select ';'+ key + '='''+value+''''
from lookups
WHERE ID IN (1,2,7,8)
for xml path('') 
),1,1,''),';',' AND ') COND
from lookups
WHERE ID IN (1,2,7,8)
) 
SELECT TOP 1 ' SELECT * FROM persons WHERE '+ COND
FROM STMT
```